# How to yank to X clipboard with VSCode Neovim extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, neovim

When using the [VSCode Neovim extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=asvetliakov.vscode-neovim) I would like the default clipboard to sync directly to X, similar to `"+y` (as mentioned by [How can I get vim yank to clipboard ("*y) working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709985/how-can-i-get-vim-yank-to-clipboard-y-working))
How can I configure Neovim to do it here?

Comment: `"+y` works for me on X. No configuration needed.

Comment: That's nice, but I'd like `y` go to X directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this mapping to automatically copy visually selected text to the system clipboard by pressing `y`

Add this to your `.vimrc`

```
vnoremap y "+y
```

Comment: Wouldn't I have to change paste etc. as well, so the registers align?

Comment: You can use `nnoremap p "+p`, to paste from system clipboard in normal mode.

Comment: Just to be clear, i don't recommend overriding the default vim's `y` and `p`, I would suggest to map it to something like Ctrl-C for copy and Ctrl-V for paste